# why doesn't putchar displays only one character when i enter more than 1 character through putchar in c programming?

Tags: c, string

I am using an IDE called Code block. Whenever I use putchar and getchar to display only a single character from a word i entered through putchar the whole word displays. why does this happened ? is there specific thing i must do the IDE. I have tried changing the type to int but the problem still lingers.

```
main()
{    
     char c;
     c= getchar();
     putchar(c);
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Enable compiler warnings, it appears that you did not include any header and your `main()` signature is wrong. And the type MUST be `int`, it's not optional.

Comment: C and C++ are **different** languages. This looks like C, but if you compile as C++, change the tag (but do not add anymore).

Comment: It's important to note that [`getchar`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) return an *`int`*.

Comment: Can you please edit you question to include what you write for input, and the actual and expected output.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't just seeing your shell echoing what you type?  Try directing the output to a file, and check the contents of the file to see what your program is really doing.

Comment: @iharob The signature of `main` is not wrong. OP uses the implicit int rule which is, while deprecated, still not wrong.

Comment: @FUZxxl Implicit int is allowed in C90, but not in C99 or later. (I don't know about C95.) Even with implicit int, it should be `main(void)` rather than `main()`.

Comment: @IanAbbott In a function definition, `foo(void)` and `foo()` is exactly the same thing and always was. And what tells you that OP doesn't program against ANSI C?

Comment: @FUZxxl: `foo(void)` mean a function that accepts no arguments; `foo()` means a function that accepts an indeterminate (but fixed!) number of arguments.

Comment: @FUZxxl I was just adding clarification. Your "still not wrong" suggested that it is still not wrong in the latest standards.

Comment: @pmg That only applies to declarations, not to definitions, cf. ISO 9899:2011 §6.7.6.3 ¶14 *“An identifier list declares only the identifiers of the parameters of the function. An empty list in a function declarator that is part of a definition of that function specifies that the function has no parameters. The empty list in a function declarator that is not part of a definition of that function specifies that no information about the number or types of the parameters is supplied.”* ANSI C contains similar language.

Comment: Thank you @FUZxxl. *remembering ... declarations only ...*

Answer (score 1):

The keyboard is *line-buffered*.

That means the Operating System only sends data to your program once it gets a whole line.

When you type `"foobar<ENTER>"` the first 'f' is only seen by your program after the ENTER is seen by the Operating System ... and by then all the characters (including the ENTER) are available to your program very very quickly (you only get that first 'f' though, unless you write some kind of loop).

*There are ways to make the keyboard behave in "unbuffered" mode, but, often, they are more trouble than they are worth. Check [ncurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses).*

Comment: This program's still only going to echo _one_ character. I suspect the user would see "`foobar\nf`" and is largely ignoring the second line of output.